# counting back generations of a number

Tags: python, loops, recursion, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to reverse engineer a set of numbers given to me (f,m) I need to go through and find how many generations it takes starting from 1,1 using the algorithm below for each generation:

```
x = 1
y = 1
new_generation = y+x
x OR y = new_generation
```

IE, I do not know if X, or Y is changed, the other variable is left the same... A list of possible outputs would look like this for the ending values of 4 and 7:

```
f = 4
m = 7
[1, 1]
[2, 1, 1, 2]
[3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3]
[4, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 5, 5, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 1, 4]
[5, 1, 4, 5, **7, 4**, 3, 7, 7, 5, 2, 7, 7, 2, 5, 7, 7, 3, **4, 7**, 5, 4, 1, 5]
```

Where every two sets of numbers (2,1) and (1,2) are a possible output. Note the ** denote the answer (in this case the order doesn't matter so long as both m and f have their value in the list).

Clearly there is exponential growth here, so I can't (or it less efficient) to make a list and then find the answer; instead I am using the following code to reverse this process...

```
def answer(m,f):
    #the variables will be sent to me as a string, so here I convert them...
    m = (int(m))
    f = (int(f))
    global counter
    #While I have not reduced my given numbers to my starting numbers....
    while m != 1 or f != 1:
        counter +=1
        #If M is greater, I know the last generation added F to M, so remove it
        if m > f:
            m = m-f
        #If F is greater, I know the last generation added M to M, so remove it
        elif f > m:
            f = f-m
        else:
            #They can never be the same (one must always be bigger, so if they are the same and NOT 1, it can't be done in any generation)
            return "impossible"
    return str(counter)

print(answer("23333","30000000000"))
```

This returns the correct answer (for instance, 4,7 returns "4" which is correct) but it takes to long when I pass larger numbers (I must be able to handle 10^50, insane amount, I know!).

---

My thought was I should be able to apply some mathematical equation to the number to reduce it and them multiple the generations, but I'm having trouble finding a way to do this that also holds the integrity of the answer (for instance, if I divide the bigger by the smaller, on small numbers (7, 300000) I get a very close (but wrong) answer, however on closer numbers such as (23333, 300000) the answer is no where even close, which makes sense due to the differences in the generation path). Note I have also tried this in a recursive function (to find generations) and using the a non-reversed method (building the list and checking the answer; which was significantly slower for obvious reasons)

---

Here are some test cases with their answers:

> ```
> f = "1"
> m = "2"
> Output: "1"
>
> f = "4"
> m = "7"
> Output: "4"
>
> f = "4"
> m = "2"
> Output: "impossible"
> ```

Any help is much appreciated! P.S. I am running Python 2.7.6

[EDIT]

---

The below code is working as desired.

```
from fractions import gcd

def answer(m,f):
    #Convert strings to ints...
    m = (int(m))
    f = (int(f))

    #If they share a common denominator (GCD) return impossible
    if gcd(m,f) != 1:
        return "impossible"
    counter = 0
    #While there is still a remainder...
    while m != 0 and f != 0:
        if m > f:
            counter += m // f
            #M now equals the remainder.
            m %= f
        elif f > m:
            counter += f // m
            f %= m
    return str(counter - 1)
```

Comment: *"I am running Python 2.7.6"* - probably not relevant to the problem, but why? It's three years old now, and not 3.x.

Comment: Can you clarify the rules? Are you saying (1,1) can go to (1+1,1) or (1,1+1)? And then (2,1) can go to (2+1,1) or (2,2+1)? So each generation is always a pair of numbers derived from the previous pair?

Comment: It has to do with legacy code I can't get away from yet; normally I like Python 3 or at least 2.7+ (it is a requirement of the project to be written in 2.7.6 and have no external dependencies)

Comment: Yes John D; that is correct, and each cycle/generation the number that changes could be different. IE if (1,1) --> (2,1 | 1,2) (it will randomly select if it is now (2,1 or 1,2)

Comment: Probably I'm missing something - still not sure how you get to (2,3) ... can you show the steps that lead from (1,1) to (2,3)?

Comment: So it would be:
[1, 1]
[2, 1] OR [2, 1]
[3, 1] OR [2, 3] (by adding 2+1 and having 2 be left alone (so we change 1))

Each set of two gets added together, then one of them becomes the aggregate, the other does not change in that set. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with the top-down approach you posted. You can speed it up by a huge factor if you use integer division instead of repeated subtraction.

```
def answer(m, f):
    m = int(m)
    f = int(f)
    counter = 0
    while m != 0 and f != 0:
        if f > m:
            m, f = f, m
        print(m, f, counter, sep="\t")
        if f != 1 and m % f == 0:
            return "impossible"
        counter += m // f
        m %= f
    return str(counter - 1)
```

Using the above, `answer(23333, 30000000000)` yields

```
30000000000 23333   0
23333   15244   1285732
15244   8089    1285733
8089    7155    1285734
7155    934 1285735
934 617 1285742
617 317 1285743
317 300 1285744
300 17  1285745
17  11  1285762
11  6   1285763
6   5   1285764
5   1   1285765
1285769
```

and `answer(4, 7)` yields

```
7   4   0
4   3   1
3   1   2
4
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of this in Python; I'm sure there is some great documentation for integer division, but would you mind explaining the base of it for me, or if you know of any good essays on how it works (I'd like to understand the function of it, not just the usage). Again, can't thank you enough!

Comment: There's not much to it. `x // y` is the operator for integer division in Python, which is equivalent to setting the decimal part of a division result to 0 (in contrast to floating-point division). Python is a bit of an exception here: in many (statically typed) languages the `/` operator already does integer division if the inputs are integers. Python outputs a floating point in such a case. The `%` (and the related `%=`) is a modulo operator, which basically calculates the remainder of an integer division.

Comment: Okay, so I did run into one new problem, my last function always returned the correct answer, simply slowly; this function works on almost everything. My test cases pass but it is failing to catch one that is impossible (I don't know the input). Any thoughts on what this might be?

Comment: I'd guess the case the case of f = n * m or m = n * f. This is impossible, too, but is not handled correctly right now.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean? I noticed that if I give it an impossible options (say, 4,2) it gives me an int (in the case of 4,2 it gives me 2) simply the wrong answer if it is not possible (I am currently working on a work around)

Comment: For anyone wondering in the future, I found a work around and made an edit to the OP with the solution code; I still consider this the best and correct answer, again thank you for refreshing my memory on the modulo operator!

Answer (score 2):

This is not a Python question, nor is it really a programming question. This is a problem designed to make you *think*. As such, if you just get the answer from somebody else, you will gain no knowledge or hindsight from the exercise.

Just add a `print(m, f)` in your `while` loop and watch how the numbers evolve for small inputs. For example, try with something like `(3, 100)`: don't you see any way you could speed things up, rather than repeatedly removing 3 from the bigger number?

Comment: I see plenty of ways to speed it up, but not without jeopardizing the evolution cycles. Further more I am not looking for a "here's the answer" I am looking for guidance in the right direction to an existing problem in my code

Comment: Well, yeah, but it's pretty much impossible to give you more guidance than I did without also revealing the answer…

Comment: Ah, indeed the answer is probably less obvious if one does not know about the integer division and modulo operators… You can find relevant info by looking for “Euclidean division” (for example at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division)).

Answer (score 0):

Try a form of recursion:

(Python 2.7.6)

```
def back():
    global f,m,i
    if f<m:
        s=m//f
        i+=s
        m-=s*f
    elif m<f:
        s=f//m
        i+=s
        f-=s*m
    else:
        return False
    return True
while True:
    f=int(raw_input('f = '))
    m=int(raw_input('m = '))
    i=0
    while True:
        if f==m==1:
            print 'Output:',str(i)
            break
        else:
            if not back():
                print 'Output: impossible'
                break
    print
```

(Python 3.5.2)

```
def back():
    global f,m,i
    if f<m:
        s=m//f
        i+=s
        m-=s*f
    elif m<f:
        s=f//m
        i+=s
        f-=s*m
    else:
        return False
    return True
while True:
    f=int(input('f = '))
    m=int(input('m = '))
    i=0
    while True:
        if f==m==1:
            print('Output:',str(i))
            break
        else:
            if not back():
                print('Output: impossible')
                break
    print()
```

Note: I am a Python 3.5 coder so I have tried to backdate my code, please let me know if there is something wrong with it.

The input format is also different: instead of `f = "some_int"` it is now `f = some_int`, and the output is formatted similarly.

Comment: I tried something similar, however you code takes ~22 seconds to complete, my code takes ~8 seconds, the list and recursion causes it to go slower (input numbers used were: 300000000000 and 23333)